# CodeDom and collection initializers

Tags: c#, code-generation, codedom, object-initializers

Is there a way to generate a dictionary initializer using the C# CodeDom? Are those supported at all?

I would like to have:

```
private IDictionary<string, string> map = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "Name", "Value" },
    ...
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not possible using the CodeDom constructs.  They were not updated for collection initializers.

LukeH has an excellent blog post on the subject of 3.5 features and the CodeDom

- [http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lukeh/archive/2007/07/11/c-3-0-and-codedom.aspx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/lukeh/c-3-0-and-codedom)

Comment: Was afraid that's the case... Thanks anyway!

Comment: The blog post linked above explains that CodeDom was not updated for the "new" C# 3.0 features and gives an example of using `CSharpCodeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource` to compile a string of code containing a LINQ expression.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it but its possibly the worst nightmare ever.. Here is how I am doing it currently. (Updated my answer to reflect the question)

```
var constructDictionary = new CodeMemberField("Dictionary<string, string> map", @" = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
   { Name, Value },
}");
```

This can also be populated once again its hackish.

```
string builder += " = new Dictionary<string, string>(){";
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   builder+="{ Name"+i+", Value"+i+" }";
}
var constructDictionary = new CodeMemberField("Dictionary<string, string> map", builder+" }");
```